# Cookies are encrypted in middleware laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, middleware, laravel-9

I enable EncryptCookies for api in kernel.php

In my Middleware/Authenticate.php file, i cant access cookies. They are encrypted.

Authenticate.php :

```
protected function authenticate($request, $guards)
{

    $token = $request->cookie('something'); // Now it stores the encryted cookie
 
}
```

Btw i can use them in my controllers.
How can i use them in middlewares

Answer (score 0):

It matters the order those  middlewares are defined. Make sure the Encrypt middleware is before Authenticate middleware.